# Regex to match any words except words with given pattern

Tags: regex, regex-negation, regex-lookarounds, regex-greedy

I want to match all words except following words :

```
1) any-random-word 
2) any-random-word/ 
3) any-random-word/123 
4) any-random-word/abcdef
```

so that following similar words can be matched.

```
1) any-random-word123
2) any-random-word(any non-word character other than '/')123
2) any-random-wordabcdef
4) any-random-word(any non-word character other than '/')abcdef
```

In fact any number or any word can be appened after 'any-random-word/'.

I tried with

```
^(?!any-random-word(\/?)(\w+)$|any-random-word$)
```

but its escaping all words having any-random-word in it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change your current regex a little:

```
^(?!.*\bany-random-word\b)
```

And if you want to actually match something, add `.+` at the end:

```
^(?!.*\bany-random-word\b).+
```

[regex101 demo](http://regex101.com/r/mG7nG8)

`\b` (a word boundary) ensures that there's no other `\w` character around the word you don't want to match.

---

Edit: As per your further clarification, I would suggest this regex:

```
^(?!.*\bany-random-word(?:/|$)).+
```

The main part of the regex is the negative lookahead: `(?!.*\bany-random-word(?:/|$))`. It will cause the whole match to fail if what's inside matches.

`.*\bany-random-word(?:/|$)` will match `any-random-word` at the end of a string or followed by `/`, anywhere in the string that it is being tested against.

So, if you have `any-random-word/`, it will match, and cause the whole match to fail. If you have the string ending in `any-random-word`, again, the whole match will fail.

Comment: This regex actually taking any speical character after any-random-word. I mean even any-random-word+ gets passed.

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear, I mean to say it should pass if its not '/', so that -any-random-word+(123/abc) will be matched.

Comment: @KundanPandit Okay, how about [this regex](http://regex101.com/r/dC0gJ4) then? If that works, I'll change my answer.

Comment: That works!! Thanks. It w'd be great if you could explain and post that as separate answer so that I can accept and would be useful for other users also.

Comment: @KundanPandit Edited my answer accordingly.